# How implement 360 rotating carousel view in android

Tags: android, carousel

I am working on carousel view to show categories. Carousel view has 360 rotation. I am using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) . Rotating carousel view is created but i have a problem. I only want to show front face of carosul view.

**Part1**

**1.** How to hide backface of carousel view?

**Part2**

I am not getting this problem when work with static images.

This library work for static carousel view elements. I made some changes in " Carousel.java" to carousel view elements load from server. But I get Exception. If i comment lines of **"getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)"** method & return i, then exception not get, but only one element shown in carousel view.

**Exception**

[Same Exception](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/issues/140)

**Carousel.java**

```
 public class Carousel extends CarouselSpinner implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
private ImageLoader imageLoaderobj;
ImageAdapter adapter;
private static final String TAG = Carousel.class.getSimpleName();
private static final boolean localLOGV = false;
private static final int MIN_QUANTITY = 3;
private static final int MAX_QUANTITY = 16;
private static final float MAX_THETA = 15.0f;
private static final int SCROLL_TO_FLING_UNCERTAINTY_TIMEOUT = 250;
private AdapterContextMenuInfo mContextMenuInfo;
    private int mAnimationDuration = 900;    
    private Camera mCamera = new Camera();
    private Runnable mDisableSuppressSelectionChangedRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     mSuppressSelectionChanged = false;
     selectionChanged();
    }
};
  private int mDownTouchPosition;
  private View mDownTouchView;
  private FlingRotateRunnable mFlingRunnable = new FlingRotateRunnable();
  private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
  private int mGravity;
  private boolean mIsFirstScroll;
  private int mMaxQuantity = MAX_QUANTITY;
  private int mMinQuantity = MIN_QUANTITY;
  private boolean mReceivedInvokeKeyDown;
  private View mSelectedChild;        
  private boolean mShouldCallbackDuringFling = true;
  private boolean mShouldCallbackOnUnselectedItemClick = true;
  private boolean mShouldStopFling;
  private boolean mSuppressSelectionChanged;
  private float mTheta = (float)(0.0f*(Math.PI/180.0)); 
  private boolean mUseReflection=false;
  public Carousel(Context context)  {
this(context, null);
    imageLoaderobj=new ImageLoader(context);
}
public Carousel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    imageLoaderobj=new ImageLoader(context);
}
public Carousel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    imageLoaderobj=new ImageLoader(context);
    setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getContext(), this);
    mGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
    setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
    TypedArray arr = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Carousel);
    mAnimationDuration = arr.getInteger(R.styleable.Carousel_android_animationDuration, 400);
    mUseReflection = arr.getBoolean(R.styleable.Carousel_UseReflection, false); 
    int selectedItem = arr.getInteger(R.styleable.Carousel_SelectedItem, 0);
        int min = arr.getInteger(R.styleable.Carousel_minQuantity, MIN_QUANTITY);
    int max = arr.getInteger(R.styleable.Carousel_maxQuantity, MAX_QUANTITY);
    float mTheta = arr.getFloat(R.styleable.Carousel_maxTheta, MAX_THETA);
    if(mTheta > MAX_THETA || mTheta < 0.0f)
        mTheta = MAX_THETA;
            mMinQuantity = min < MIN_QUANTITY ? MIN_QUANTITY : min;
    mMaxQuantity = max > MAX_QUANTITY ? MAX_QUANTITY : max;
        if(arr.length() < mMinQuantity || arr.length() > mMaxQuantity)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid set of items.");
        }
/** customize carouselview programmitically  */
    public void initilize(ArrayList<String> images,ArrayList<String> names,int selectedItem)
    {   adapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext());
        adapter.SetImages(images, names, mUseReflection);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           setAdapter(adapter);
        if(selectedItem < 0 || selectedItem >= adapter.getCount())
            selectedItem = 0;
        // next time we go through layout with this value
        setNextSelectedPositionInt(selectedItem);
    }
    public void adapterNotify()
    {   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
protected int computeHorizontalScrollExtent() {
   return 1;
}
  @Override
protected int computeHorizontalScrollOffset() {
    return mSelectedPosition;
}
     @Override
protected int computeHorizontalScrollRange() {
         return mItemCount;
}
   @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean retValue = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        onUp();
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        onCancel();
    }
    return retValue;
}       
  @Override
protected ContextMenuInfo getContextMenuInfo() {
    return mContextMenuInfo;
}    
  @Override
public boolean showContextMenu() {
     if (isPressed() && mSelectedPosition >= 0) {
      int index = mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition;
      View v = getChildAt(index);
      return dispatchLongPress(v, mSelectedPosition, mSelectedRowId);
    }        
     return false;
}
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
       ////if (movePrevious()) {
           playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.NAVIGATION_LEFT);
       ////}
       return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
       /////if (moveNext()) {
           playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.NAVIGATION_RIGHT);
       ////}
       return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
       mReceivedInvokeKeyDown = true;
      }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
  @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER: {
                 if (mReceivedInvokeKeyDown) {
            if (mItemCount > 0) {
                  dispatchPress(mSelectedChild);
                postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dispatchUnpress();
                    }
                }, ViewConfiguration.getPressedStateDuration());

                int selectedIndex = mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition;
                performItemClick(getChildAt(selectedIndex), mSelectedPosition, mAdapter
                        .getItemId(mSelectedPosition));
            }
        }
                 mReceivedInvokeKeyDown = false;
                    return true;
    }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}    
        @Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
           if (gainFocus && mSelectedChild != null) {
        mSelectedChild.requestFocus(direction);
    }
  }       
  @Override
   protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return p instanceof LayoutParams;
 }
  @Override
protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return new LayoutParams(p);
}
  @Override
public ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
}
  @Override
public void dispatchSetSelected(boolean selected) {
      }
 @Override
protected void dispatchSetPressed(boolean pressed) {
    if (mSelectedChild != null) {
       mSelectedChild.setPressed(pressed);
    }
}
  @Override
public boolean showContextMenuForChild(View originalView) {
    final int longPressPosition = getPositionForView(originalView);
    if (longPressPosition < 0) {
      return false;
    }        final long longPressId = mAdapter.getItemId(longPressPosition);
    return dispatchLongPress(originalView, longPressPosition, longPressId);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return event.dispatch(this, null, null);
}        @Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    ArrayList<CarouselItem> sl = new ArrayList<CarouselItem>();
    for(int j = 0; j < childCount; j++)
    {   CarouselItem view = (CarouselItem)getAdapter().getView(j,null, null);
    if(i == 0)
    view.setDrawn(false);
    sl.add((CarouselItem)getAdapter().getView(j,null, null));
        }
    Collections.sort(sl);
     // Get first undrawn item in array and get result index
    int idx = 0;
    for(CarouselItem civ : sl)
    {
    if(!civ.isDrawn())
    {   civ.setDrawn(true);
        idx = civ.getIndex();
        break;
    }
        }
    return idx;
}
    @Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation transformation) {
    transformation.clear();
    transformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
    float centerX = (float)getWidth()/2, centerY = (float)getHeight()/2;
    mCamera.save();
    final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
    mCamera.translate(((CarouselItem)child).getItemX(), ((CarouselItem)child).getItemY(), 
    ((CarouselItem)child).getItemZ());
    mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    mCamera.restore();
    Matrix mm = new Matrix();
    mm.setValues(values);
    ((CarouselItem)child).setCIMatrix(mm);
    child.invalidate();
    return true;
}     
    void layout(int delta, boolean animate){
     if (mDataChanged) {
        handleDataChanged();
    }
             if (getCount() == 0) {
        resetList();
        return;
    }
            if (mNextSelectedPosition >= 0) {
        setSelectedPositionInt(mNextSelectedPosition);
    }        
        recycleAllViews();        
              detachAllViewsFromParent();
                 int count = getAdapter().getCount();
    float angleUnit = 360.0f / count;
   float angleOffset = mSelectedPosition * angleUnit;
    for(int i = 0; i< getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
        float angle = angleUnit * i - angleOffset;
        if(angle < 0.0f)
            angle = 360.0f + angle;
        makeAndAddView(i, angle);           
    }
          mRecycler.clear();
    invalidate();
    setNextSelectedPositionInt(mSelectedPosition);
            checkSelectionChanged();
                mNeedSync = false;
           updateSelectedItemMetadata();
    } 
    @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
     mInLayout = true;
    layout(0, false);
    mInLayout = false;
}       
  @Override
void selectionChanged() {
    if (!mSuppressSelectionChanged) {
        super.selectionChanged();
    }
}    
  @Override
void setSelectedPositionInt(int position) {
    super.setSelectedPositionInt(position);
    super.setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);
         updateSelectedItemMetadata();
}
private class FlingRotateRunnable implements Runnable {
        private Rotator mRotator;
    private float mLastFlingAngle;
        public FlingRotateRunnable(){
        mRotator = new Rotator(getContext());
    }
    private void startCommon() {
                removeCallbacks(this);
    }
    public void startUsingVelocity(float initialVelocity) {
        if (initialVelocity == 0) return;
                  startCommon();
                    mLastFlingAngle = 0.0f;
                    mRotator.fling(initialVelocity);
               post(this);
    }        
            public void startUsingDistance(float deltaAngle) {
        if (deltaAngle == 0) return;
               startCommon();
               mLastFlingAngle = 0;
        synchronized(this)
        {
            mRotator.startRotate(0.0f, -deltaAngle, mAnimationDuration);
        }
        post(this);
    }
    public void stop(boolean scrollIntoSlots) {
        removeCallbacks(this);
        endFling(scrollIntoSlots);
    }        
    private void endFling(boolean scrollIntoSlots) {
     synchronized(this){
    mRotator.forceFinished(true);
        }
                 if (scrollIntoSlots) scrollIntoSlots();
    }
        public void run() {
        if (Carousel.this.getChildCount() == 0) {
            endFling(true);
            return;
        }           
            mShouldStopFling = false;
                final Rotator rotator;
        final float angle;
        boolean more;
        synchronized(this){
            rotator = mRotator;
            more = rotator.computeAngleOffset();
            angle = rotator.getCurrAngle();             
        }
           float delta = mLastFlingAngle - angle;                        
        trackMotionScroll(delta);
            if (more && !mShouldStopFling) {
            mLastFlingAngle = angle;
            post(this);
        } else {
            mLastFlingAngle = 0.0f;
            endFling(true);
        }            
            }
    }
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
     private ArrayList<CarouselItem> mImages;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }       
        public void SetImages(ArrayList<String> array, ArrayList<String> names, boolean reflected)
    {

        if(names != null)
            if(array.size() != names.size())
                throw new RuntimeException("Images and names arrays length doesn't match");
            final int reflectionGap = 4;
        mImages=new ArrayList<CarouselItem>();
        for(int i = 0; i< array.size(); i++)
        {
            Bitmap originalImage=imageLoaderobj.getBitmap(array.get(i)) ;               if(originalImage!=null)
            {
            originalImage=AppUtiles.getCroppedBitmap(originalImage);
            if(reflected){
                int width = originalImage.getWidth();
                int height = originalImage.getHeight();
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preScale(1, -1);
                                Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                        height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);
                Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                        (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
                // Draw in the original image
                canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
                // Draw in the gap
                Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap,
                        deafaultPaint);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap,
                        null);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
                        originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap,
                        0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);                    // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
                paint.setShader(shader);                    
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
                gradient
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

                originalImage = bitmapWithReflection;
            }

            CarouselItem item = new CarouselItem(mContext);
            item.setIndex(i);
            item.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
            if(names != null)
                item.setText(names.get(i));

            mImages.add(item);
            }
        }
                }
    public int getCount() {
        if(mImages == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return mImages.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView=mImages.get(position);
        if(mImages.get(position).getCurrentAngle()<270&&mImages.get(position).getCurrentAngle()>90)
        {
            convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
         return convertView;
    }

}       

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
           mFlingRunnable.stop(false);

    mDownTouchPosition = pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
            if (mDownTouchPosition >= 0) {
        mDownTouchView = getChildAt(mDownTouchPosition - mFirstPosition);
        mDownTouchView.setPressed(true);
    }
                  mIsFirstScroll = true;
                 return true;
}   
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (!mShouldCallbackDuringFling) {
                               // Remove any future code to set mSuppressSelectionChanged = false
        removeCallbacks(mDisableSuppressSelectionChangedRunnable);
        if (!mSuppressSelectionChanged) mSuppressSelectionChanged = true;
    }

    mFlingRunnable.startUsingVelocity((int) velocityX);
            return true;
}
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mDownTouchPosition < 0) {
        return;
    }
     performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
    long id = getItemIdAtPosition(mDownTouchPosition);
    dispatchLongPress(mDownTouchView, mDownTouchPosition, id);

}
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {

    if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(e2.getX() - e1.getX()));
           getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    if (!mShouldCallbackDuringFling) {
        if (mIsFirstScroll) {
                            if (!mSuppressSelectionChanged) mSuppressSelectionChanged = true;
            postDelayed(mDisableSuppressSelectionChangedRunnable, SCROLL_TO_FLING_UNCERTAINTY_TIMEOUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (mSuppressSelectionChanged) mSuppressSelectionChanged = false;
    }
            trackMotionScroll(/* -1 * */ (int) distanceX);
           mIsFirstScroll = false;
    return true;
 }
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    if (mDownTouchPosition >= 0) {
                if (mShouldCallbackOnUnselectedItemClick || mDownTouchPosition == mSelectedPosition) {
            performItemClick(mDownTouchView, mDownTouchPosition, mAdapter
                    .getItemId(mDownTouchPosition));
        }
                    return true;
    }
            return false;
}
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}

private void Calculate3DPosition(CarouselItem child, int diameter, float angleOffset){

    angleOffset = angleOffset * (float)(Math.PI/180.0f);        

    float x = - (float)(diameter/2  * android.util.FloatMath.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter/2 - child.getWidth()/2;
    float z = diameter/2 * (1.0f - (float)android.util.FloatMath.cos(angleOffset));
    float y = - getHeight()/2 + (float) (z * android.util.FloatMath.sin(mTheta));
    child.setItemX(x);
    child.setItemZ(z);
    child.setItemY(y);
       }
   private int calculateTop(View child, boolean duringLayout) {
    int myHeight = duringLayout ? getMeasuredHeight() : getHeight();
    int childHeight = duringLayout ? child.getMeasuredHeight() : child.getHeight(); 
            int childTop = 0;
    switch (mGravity) {
    case Gravity.TOP:
        childTop = mSpinnerPadding.top;
        break;
    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
        int availableSpace = myHeight - mSpinnerPadding.bottom
                - mSpinnerPadding.top - childHeight;
        childTop = mSpinnerPadding.top + (availableSpace / 2);
        break;
    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
        childTop = myHeight - mSpinnerPadding.bottom - childHeight;
        break;
    }
    return childTop;
}       
    private boolean dispatchLongPress(View view, int position, long id) {
    boolean handled = false;
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
        handled = mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(this, mDownTouchView,
                mDownTouchPosition, id);
    }
    if (!handled) {
        mContextMenuInfo = new AdapterContextMenuInfo(view, position, id);
        handled = super.showContextMenuForChild(this);
    }
    if (handled) {
        performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
    }
     return handled;
}    
    private void dispatchPress(View child) {
       if (child != null) {
        child.setPressed(true);
    }
       setPressed(true);
}
   private void dispatchUnpress() {
        for (int i = getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        getChildAt(i).setPressed(false);
    }
        setPressed(false);
}            
private int getCenterOfGallery() {
    return (getWidth() - Carousel.this.getPaddingLeft() - Carousel.this.getPaddingRight()) / 2 + 
        Carousel.this.getPaddingLeft();
}   
  private static int getCenterOfView(View view) {
    return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
}   
    float getLimitedMotionScrollAmount(boolean motionToLeft, float deltaX) {
    int extremeItemPosition = motionToLeft ? Carousel.this.getCount() - 1 : 0;
    View extremeChild = getChildAt(extremeItemPosition - Carousel.this.getFirstVisiblePosition());
          if (extremeChild == null) {
        return deltaX;
    }
           int extremeChildCenter = getCenterOfView(extremeChild);
    int galleryCenter = getCenterOfGallery();
            if (motionToLeft) {
        if (extremeChildCenter <= galleryCenter) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (extremeChildCenter >= galleryCenter) {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    int centerDifference = galleryCenter - extremeChildCenter;

    return motionToLeft
            ? Math.max(centerDifference, deltaX)
            : Math.min(centerDifference, deltaX); 
}
   int getLimitedMotionScrollAmount(boolean motionToLeft, int deltaX) {
    int extremeItemPosition = motionToLeft ? mItemCount - 1 : 0;
    View extremeChild = getChildAt(extremeItemPosition - mFirstPosition);

    if (extremeChild == null) {
        return deltaX;
    }
            int extremeChildCenter = getCenterOfView(extremeChild);
    int galleryCenter = getCenterOfGallery();
            if (motionToLeft) {
        if (extremeChildCenter <= galleryCenter) {
                         return 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (extremeChildCenter >= galleryCenter) {
            return 0;
        }
    }    
       int centerDifference = galleryCenter - extremeChildCenter;
    return motionToLeft
            ? Math.max(centerDifference, deltaX)
            : Math.min(centerDifference, deltaX); 
}    
   private void makeAndAddView(int position, float angleOffset) {
    CarouselItem child;
      if (!mDataChanged) {
        child = (CarouselItem)mRecycler.get(position);
        if (child != null) {
            setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);
        }
        else
        {                                child = (CarouselItem)mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);

            // Position the view
            setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);               
        }
        return;
    }
    child = (CarouselItem)mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);
    setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);
   }      
    void onCancel(){
    onUp();
}
private void onFinishedMovement() {
    if (mSuppressSelectionChanged) {
        mSuppressSelectionChanged = false;
              super.selectionChanged();
    }
    checkSelectionChanged();
    invalidate();

}    
    void onUp(){
    if (mFlingRunnable.mRotator.isFinished()) {
        scrollIntoSlots();
    }        
    dispatchUnpress();      
}
    private void scrollIntoSlots(){
            if (getChildCount() == 0 || mSelectedChild == null) return;
            float angle; 
    int position;
        ArrayList<CarouselItem> arr = new ArrayList<CarouselItem>();

    for(int i = 0; i < getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
        arr.add(((CarouselItem)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null)));
            Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<CarouselItem>(){
        public int compare(CarouselItem c1, CarouselItem c2) {
            int a1 = (int)c1.getCurrentAngle();
            if(a1 > 180)
                a1 = 360 - a1;
            int a2 = (int)c2.getCurrentAngle();
            if(a2 > 180)
                a2 = 360 - a2;
            return (a1 - a2) ;
        }           
    });

    angle = arr.get(0).getCurrentAngle();
        if(angle > 180.0f)
        angle = -(360.0f - angle);
         if(angle != 0.0f)
    {           mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(-angle);
    }
    else
    {                  position = arr.get(0).getIndex();
        setSelectedPositionInt(position);
        onFinishedMovement();
    }
}
void scrollToChild(int i){      
    CarouselItem view = (CarouselItem)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
    float angle = view.getCurrentAngle();
            if(angle == 0)
        return;
            if(angle > 180.0f)
        angle = 360.0f - angle;
    else
        angle = -angle;

    mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(angle);
}    
   public void setCallbackDuringFling(boolean shouldCallback) {
    mShouldCallbackDuringFling = shouldCallback;
}

public void setCallbackOnUnselectedItemClick(boolean shouldCallback) {
    mShouldCallbackOnUnselectedItemClick = shouldCallback;
}   
public void setAnimationDuration(int animationDurationMillis) {
    mAnimationDuration = animationDurationMillis;
}
    public void setGravity(int gravity){
    if (mGravity != gravity) {
        mGravity = gravity;
        requestLayout();
    }
}      

private void setUpChild(CarouselItem child, int index, float angleOffset) {
      addViewInLayout(child, -1 /*index*/, generateDefaultLayoutParams());
    child.setSelected(index == mSelectedPosition);
      int h;
    int w;
    int d;
       if(mInLayout)
    {
        w = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        d = getMeasuredWidth();
       }
    else
    {       w = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        d = getWidth();
          }
    child.setCurrentAngle(angleOffset);
       child.measure(w, h);
  int childLeft;
        int childTop = calculateTop(child, true);
        childLeft = 0;
  child.layout(childLeft, childTop, w, h);
     Calculate3DPosition(child, d, angleOffset);

} 
     void trackMotionScroll(float deltaAngle) {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }
           for(int i = 0; i < getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
                CarouselItem child = (CarouselItem)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            float angle = child.getCurrentAngle();
        angle += deltaAngle;

        while(angle > 360.0f)
            angle -= 360.0f;

        while(angle < 0.0f)
            angle += 360.0f;

        child.setCurrentAngle(angle);
        Calculate3DPosition(child, getWidth(), angle);
               }
          mRecycler.clear();        
            invalidate();
}   
   private void updateSelectedItemMetadata() {
            View oldSelectedChild = mSelectedChild;
    View child = mSelectedChild = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition);
    if (child == null) {
        return;
    }
    child.setSelected(true);
    child.setFocusable(true);
    if (hasFocus()) {
        child.requestFocus();
    }
          if (oldSelectedChild != null) {
                   oldSelectedChild.setSelected(false);
                  oldSelectedChild.setFocusable(false);
    }
      }
       }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try to do it by yourself and show what you did, before asking...

Comment: I tried it, but not resolve it.

Comment: you updated the carousel of CodeProject, to hide the backface ? if yes , share what you did... else if you have just copied the code without trying to costumize it to your need , then good luck ...

Comment: i have try to customize by changing angles & changes in X, Y, z values fo Carousel.java class of code project.

Comment: Also I have success to resolve one requirement (to make backface & front at same level ) by setting max angle to 0.

Comment: I try is by customize some of methods - Calculate3DPosition(), makeAndAddView(i, angle) & by changing angles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I used the same library you're using, but I think I had a similar issue to part 2 at one point. Make sure that you're either providing a placeholder image or specifically set the dimensions of the items in the carousel, so that while they're loading from the server the carousel can still do all it's measurements correctly.

Comment: @ I am not using placeholder.After downloadind bitmap from server I scale it require height & width

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: The carousel uses the dimensions of the views to set itself up. If you don't have a placeholder or a layout for each item which sets the size, it thinks the size is 0, which screws things up. Make sure that the layout you're using in your adapter sets it's dimensions explicitly (rather than using wrap_content), or use a placeholder image so that it can use that to measure the dimensions of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager and create a function that will change the view every certain amount of second so that it will look like a carousel.

Comment: but how give it circular shape?